# Making a Reddit bot, and i am getting a IndexError

Tags: python, python-3.x, reddit, praw, index-error

I have 3 lines of code where it says it is a problem.
First line:

```
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit(subreddits[pos])
```

Second line:

```
post()
```

Third(also the second):

```
post()
```

I already defined *post*, and it's not giving me a def error.
Could it be something with my *for* loop?

```
if (pos >= len(subreddits) - 1):
    post()
else:
    print("Done")
```

EDIT: Pylint doesn't pick it up before I debug (Since I'm coding in VS Code)

EDIT2: Image of error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWp3Z.jpg

Comment: Please add the actual traceback of the error

Comment: Why use indexes anyways? Couldn't you just use something like `for subreddit in subreddits:`? It's hard to know without seeing your actual code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for **not** posting images of errors. Also, thank you for your efforts in creating a [mcve]. Unfortunately you minimized it so much that we cannot run it to test.